# How does Sentry catch the exception

Tags: java, sentry

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof ClientAbortException && e.getMessage().contains("Broken pipe")){
        logger.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }else {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        Sentry.captureException(e);
    }
```

I don't need sentry to capture the ClientAbortExcption "Broken pipe", so I use the "if" to prevent sentry to capture and send email. But I receive an email is as followed.
[image]

and I am sure the exception is caught in the above code.

why, how I do to avoid the problem happened again.

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing more of the code and the details of the exception. Id suggest you use a debugger to step into the catch block and see what actually happens. Also, it would help if you share the full stacktrace. Maybe it is coming from a different catch block. There are many possibilities and we can not answer it other than by pure guessing. Voting to close, missing debug info.

Comment: I have done the relevant debugger operations. There is no problem in the local environment. This problem occurs in the online environment

Comment: Again, people on StackOverflow are not meant to _guess_. If we have to guess the answer to your problem, you will instead receive down- and close-votes. You are supposed to ask your question in a way that helpers can answer it without guessing, by providing enough details on everything (see [ask]). So if you can not provide everything needed for people to figure out the cause, you wont receive help.

Comment: Looks like the `ClientAbortException` is wrapping an `IOException`. The message could be somewhere in the `cause` chain.

Comment: ok, sincerely thank you.